# Bokeh Hovertools is not showing a hover at all

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, geopandas

I'm trying to plot coordinates from the following dataframe `gvri_df`:

```
   id   ob       x                y
0   1   1   121877.864934   487888.548119
1   2   2   121772.572154   487952.500882
2   3   3   121824.001607   487927.953991
3   4   4   121887.380073   486978.455422
4   5   5   117820.122667   487964.987875
```

using the following code

```
source = ColumnDataSource(gvri_df)

hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips=[('VRI', '@id'),
                ('Kruispunt', '@ob')]

p.add_tools(hover)

# Plotting
p = figure(title="VRI")
p.circle('x', 'y', source=source, color='red', size=5)


show(p)
```

It nicely outputs the plot as expected except that it does not show a hover at all. Like the tool was not added to the plot.

[image: plot]

Am I doing something wrong or does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `p.add_tools(hover)` before you execute `p = figure(...)`. It seems like you have provided just part of the code and that the hover tool ends up being added to some other plot.

To avoid such mistakes, do not reuse variables - you don't save any resources by doing that but increase the probability of making a mistake.

Comment: Thanks! I totally overlooked this. Fixed my problem